# Facebook API: What language are the locations returned in?

Tags: facebook, internationalization

I searched Facebook's documentation, but could find it. In what language are the locations (for example, for checkins) returned in the Facebook API? In the application's language, in the current user's language, in the original language or in the local language?

How can I be sure that the locations are always returned in, lets say, English?

So `Roma` is returned as `Rome`, `Praha` as `Prague` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible:

- Editing a Place page on facebook.com doesn't present any internationalisation options
- The Translations app seems geared towards translating Facebook's static content from English into other languages, rather than translating user-generated content into arbitrary languages
- The only column of the [FQL `place` table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/place/) which is affected by the request `locale` parameter is `display_subtext` ([example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20name%2Cdescription%2Cgeometry%2Clatitude%2Clongitude%2Ccheckin_count%2Cdisplay_subtext%20FROM%20place%20WHERE%20page_id%3D138551696187707%26locale%3Des_ES))
- The only attribute of the [Graph API `user/checkins` connection](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/) affected by the request `locale` parameter is `application.name` ([example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Fcheckins%3Flocale%3Dja_JP))

I think you're limited to whatever language(s) the Place creator/editors have used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this behaviour doesn't help too much in my application, I'll need to find a workaround.